# How to calculate the number of values inside of an array with multiple arrays in one for loop?

Tags: java, arrays

The code i am working with is below.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++)
    {
        j=0;
        System.out.println(playerNames[i] + "'s turn!");

        while(userChoice != 2 && j < 5) 
        {
            Die roll2 = new Die();
            roll2.roll();
            System.out.println(roll2);

            diceArray[i][j] = roll2;

            System.out.println("Again? 1= yes, 2=no");
            userChoice = scan.nextInt();
            j++;

        }

        if(userChoice == 2)
        {
            userChoice = 1;


        }


    }
```

And i am wondering, How could i add a counter, to see how many values are in each row of the array, this is a 2D array, which will have an unknown number of rows, and less than 5 columns. (It could be 5, could be 1.). I cannot do this with a simple count++ because of the multiple rows.

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: `diceArray.length` will return the number of `rows` in the array and `diceArray[0].length` will return the number of `columns` (number of values associated with each row) which i believe is what you are looking for.

Comment: So if i wanted to save those values, I could do like int arrayLength = diceArray.length?

Comment: @3kings is correct, although just using `playerCount` for the rows will save you the negligible amount of time calling `diceArray.length` will take.

Comment: @JonRoy Yeah. `arrayLength` would then be the value of how many `int[]`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of columns for a row in a 2D array using `array[i].length`. For example:

```
for(int row=0; row < array.length; row++) {
    System.out.println("Num Of Col for row " + row + ": " + array[row].length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way i could get this to disregard the entries that are null? I had to set a column value over 0, so i could initialize the 2D array?

Comment: @JonRoy in Java the default values for an array entries that are of type int is 0. If you want to modify the values (different than zero), you will need to write a nested loop that goes from `col = 0` to `array[row].length`, and modify the value `array[row][col] = NEW_INT`